# Unable to find click Button locator in robotframework- selenium

Tags: robotframework

I started to learn robot framework and writing simple UI test case to login jenkins using chrome browser. Here is my robot code.

```
Enter User Name
    Input Text    name=j_username    ${Username}

Enter Password
    Input Text    name=j_password    ${Password}

Click Login
    click button    submit-button
```

I am able to get j_username and j_password from source code but somehow I am not able to find correct locator for click button. Here is html code

```
class="clear">
<div id="side-panel"></div>
<div id="main-panel">
    <a name="skip2content"></a>
    <div style="margin: 2em;">
    <form method="post" name="login" action="j_acegi_security_check" style="text-size:smaller">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td align="right">
                 <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" /></td>
             <td><label for="remember_me">Remember me on this computer</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="from" type="hidden" value="/" />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="log in" class="submit-button primary" />
<script>
```

I tried `name=submit  value=log in` but no luck

Comment: html code : <td>User:</td><td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /></td></tr><tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td></tr><tr><td align="right"><input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" /></td><td><label for="remember_me">Remember me on this computer</label></td></tr></table><input name="from" type="hidden" value="/" /><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="log in" class="submit-button primary" /><script>

Comment: please fix your question to include the html code properly marked up so that we can read it. I've fixed the robot code but it's going to be too time-consuming for me to fix the  html.

Comment: When you say "but no luck", what does that mean? Do you get an error? Does it click the wrong button? Does the script crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are trying to click a button, but your "submit-button" is an input (So you can use Click Element instead of Click Button).

Secondly, the class attribute is not an implicit locator in Robot Framework. 
Implicit locators are the id or name attributes. 
Check this: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Locating%20elements

So you can use this:

```
Click Login
    Click Element    class:submit-login
```

or this(name attribute):

```
Click Login
    Click Element    Submit
```

Comment: perfect Cris..this fixed the issue. Thanks